# Excel Formula to display text based on value of two cells

Tags: excel, criteria

Im looking for a way to display text of a cell based on the below two conditions :

1. If Cell C20 contains certain words like "ghan", "ERC", "VSL" **AND** cell D22 is <> "-" then cell i22 should display the content of cell C20.
2. If cell C20 does not contain any of these words regardless whether D22 is ="-" or contains a number it should remain as "-"

Screenshot attached

Here's what i have tried so far :

```
1) =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Aug!I555),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ERC",Aug!B555))),Aug!B555,"-")
2) =IF(ISNUMBER(Aug!I596),Aug!B596,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*ERC*",Aug!B596)),Aug!B596,"-"))
```

This is what im using for now as a temporary solution

```
3) =IF(D22<>"-",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ghantoot",C20)),C20,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sand",C20)),C20,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("vsl",C20)),C20,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("wet",C20)),C20,"-")))))
```

[image]

Comment: None of it works.

Comment: First the formula should validate if the first cell is a number or "-". If the cell is a number then next it has to validate if the second cell is containing any text with "*ERC*" (Wildcard helps ?). If the both logicals are true then the value of the cell will become = to second cell containing ERC. If first logical is not a number then it shouldnt proceed further searching if containing ERC or not and should just display "-"

Comment: A sample screenshot of your query should be helpful for us

Comment: I have added a screenshot and rephrased everything.

Answer (score 0):

In I22:

```
    =IF(ISNUMBER(D22),
        IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ghan",C20)),
              ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ERC",C20)),
              ISNUMBER(SEARCH("VSL",C20))),
           C20,
           "-"),
        IF(D22="-","-","d22 not number & not -"))
```

I don't think you stated what happens with all branches of the logic, so I have put placeholder text there for you to fill in yourself. This is:

- "d22 not number & not -"